# Dispatching a key event in Firefox 12

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keypress, dispatchevent

I used to dispatch a key event in FireFox 10 and 11. Recently I update my browser to FireFox 12 and dispatching stop working.

[Here is a sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/EshwS/4/) of what I've been done.

When you run it in Firefox 11 or less, you can find a character printed in the textbox.

Why it doesn't work in Firefox 12, and how can I fix it? Any alternative solution is also appropriated.

Comment: What's wrong? The event *is* fired: http://jsfiddle.net/EshwS/5/

Comment: it doesn't work in FF 12. There are several machines here, I check it on all of them. It's working on FF 11, 10, 9,...

Comment: Define "Does not work". In my demo, in FF 12.0, an alert shows up: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rxxwd.png

Comment: In older versions, this code prints the 1740 character in the input, while the input remains empty in new version of FF.

Comment: For which purpose you wanna do that? unit testing? why not just referencing the input node and applying a value to fill it?

Comment: @TobiasKrogh: I've to switch the keyboard for some input tags in my web apps. There are some inputs accept English characters and some others accept Persian. User should not have to switch language of their OS. On keypress event, I change the character he entered. For example he enter 'd' and I convert it from 100 to 1470 using a char map.

Comment: @TobiasKrogh: And what's that negative vote for?!

Comment: not mine... for me input remains empty in Chrome 18 and Chromium 20 as well...

Comment: ok, so why not observing keypress event and just checking the entered keyCode and then replace the value of the element and preventing the default action?

Comment: @TobiasKrogh: This is a part of a large library which observes keypress event. It's responsible to check some other short-keys such as Ctrl+Alt and Shift+Space and such things to handle Persian dictation completely. It's an Old library (raised with jquery 1.2). In addition, I want to know the reason why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is their answer in [BugZilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=749185). Dispatching key event seem's to be rejected anymore for security reasons:

> Please note that initKeyEvent() still works. Editors just refuse the key events for both security and unclear in current spec.

But I still can't realize why my dispatched event is untrusted.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just assign the value (character #1740) to the inputbox on page load? Like:

```
$('#name').val(String.fromCharCode(1740))​;
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EvcKE/)

Answer (score 1):

check my fiddle with an empty input observing the keypress event and then replacing the input when entering an "A"... try it out

EDIT: this might work different in other browsers but is working for me in modern browsers like Firefox and Chrome / Chromium... holder IEs might behave different when observing an event

EDIT 2: updated [fiddle rev 1](http://jsfiddle.net/mpuJY/1/) to also hold a global mapping like you suggested... a small sidenote: some browsers might not support to retrieve the entered key code from `event.keyCode` so check `event.which` as well (jQuery would combine them into `event.which` and would also enable you to easily observe the keypress cross-browser).

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpuJY/)

Comment: Korgh: Here is your bug:
1. Press 'A'
2. Select input text
3. Press 'A' again
Input text should be replaced with newly pressed key char (1740), however you will see two 1740 characters in the input.

Comment: first of all it is Krogh not Korgh... second: bug? it is not like you asked directly for it or gave a code sample that did what you wanted... I only wanted to help you and give you an impression of how you could start... looking at my description the code of my fiddle is absolutely correct... I never stated to build a fully working solution for you, did I? (negative vote means this is a wrong / bad answer but it is not)

Comment: I even voted up for your question so it gains a 0 rather than a -1 to get more attention for it so we get a good answer... but blaming me for "bugs" (which aren't any at all regarding the fiddle) is mean

Comment: I never vote you down dude! I mentioned a bug of your kind suggestion, I mean, there is a problem with that solution. I tried to apply your solution and replace my method. Thank you so much for your helps and attentions Tobias and pardon me for my bad grammar.